# Very very energetic puppy

Tags: dogs

My puppy Mia is 1 year old and very energetic. She jumps and barks when she plays. and when you walk, she wants to play with you. I was concerned because my older boy dog, Mojo, did not act like that when he was her age. Is that normal for puppies?

Comment: Yes, high energy is normal for puppies, kittens, and children.

Comment: A tired puppy is a good puppy. Give her plenty of exercise: long walks, playing fetch, etc. Challenge her mentally through obedience training and dog sports like nose work.

Comment: What breed of dog is Mia?  Some breeds are more energetic and playful than others, although in general this is totally normal for a puppy.

Comment: Related [My dog is becoming unusually hyper. Whining, won't hold still, and jumping/nipping at me](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13677)

Answer (score 3):

This is very normal behaviour for a 1 year old dog.  Dogs are energetic and do like to play especially certain breeds.  I wouldn't be too disgruntled over it or worried.